# Browser back button handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I am trying to handle browser back button event but i could not find any solution.

I want to ask user if he clicks on browser back button using "confirm box" if he chooses ok i have to allow back button action else i have to stop back button action.

Can any one help me in implementing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589478/strategies-for-preserving-form-data-on-tab-browser-close

Comment: This was possibly already answered in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

Comment: Your question is either how to implement history buttons in JavaScript, or that TildalWave and Paul mentioned.

Comment: As TildalWave and Paul mentioned but i want to handle only back button event not page reloading and page closing events.

Comment: research `onbeforeunload`, start in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) Not sure what you are thnking but back button initiates page close event and that is all you can work with

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Warn/confirm User if Back button is Pressed is as below.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost."; };
```

You can get more information using below mentioned links.

[**Disable Back Button in Browser using JavaScript**](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: This solution works only for IE browser but it does not works on Chrome and Firefox browser. Can any one please provide special JS scripts so that we can handles the back button on all browsers....

Comment: @BhanuprasadKunde - You are mistaken when you say that onebeforeunload only works with IE. It works with IE,FF,chrome and Opera. Check for implementation errors in javascript console.

Comment: can confirm, `window.onbeforeunload` works also in Chrome, FF (Opera? - i dont test it)

Comment: This only works in Firefox if you have interacted with the website

Comment: Second link "Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript" seems to be dead

Comment: Yes,you're right.I have removed that link.Thanks :) @CyrilDuchon-Doris

Answer (score 14):

You can also add hash when page is loading:

```
location.hash = "noBack";
```

Then just handle location hash change to add another hash:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    location.hash = "noBack";
});
```

**That makes hash always present and back button tries to remove hash at first.** Hash is then added again by "hashchange" handler - so page would never actually can be changed to previous one.

Comment: Be careful with handling href="#id" then ;)