# How can I detect a user about the exit the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back

I would like to detect when a user is about to exit the page, **before they click the back button**, and do something - for example display a popup. I do not want to prevent the user from leaving the page, but only to grab their attention again.

This is already done by [Optin Monster](http://optinmonster.com/), but I want to implement it myself.

Where to start?

Edit:
`beforeunload` is fired **after** the user clicked the back or x button. I would like to catch his **exit intent**, for example when the mouse is moving towards the back button, but before it was clicked.

Comment: That's going to be tricky, if not impossible. For one, a browser's back button is outside of the scope of the document loaded in it, so the document has no way (?) of detecting events like `hover` on a browser's chrome. You can, theoretically, try to guess based on a mouse pointer's movement _from document to browser chrome_ (like direction and speed), but that's sketchy, problematic cross-browser, and hacky at best. Besides, I can just press `BKSP` on my keyboard, and it'll do the same thing, effectively circumventing your "exit intent" detection.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan that's the right direction. I wonder if there exists a plugin that does just that..

Comment: https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce maybe But just binding a window mouseleave eveznt could be enough imho

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543245/browser-back-button-handling

Comment: @Tzach ~ I'd argue "right direction", but to humor you, no I haven't heard of any.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan in my opinion this is a better approach than a popup that actually interferes with the back button..

Comment: @A.Wolff this is actually what I'm looking for! Please post as an answer.

Comment: Have you guys ever head of .mousemove() ?

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev Have you ever check how many times mousemove handler is fired, especially on document/window level? ;)

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could vote to close questions solely on the grounds that it's a terrible idea that should never be implemented anyway.

Comment: You can track clicking back button with 100% accuracy and not using mouse movement. By replacing browser history zero state (if user enters site from other domain) with your custom url, maybe the current url with some get parameters which will trigger some modal. And listening to popstate. U can even achieve the same result if browser doesnt support history states only with really hacky version. I have coded and implemented this feature.

Answer (score 23):

[Ouibounce](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce) does this. There is a [live demo here](http://carlsednaoui.github.io/ouibounce/).

```
npm install ouibounce
```

Then:

```
var ouibounce = require('ouibounce');
var modal = document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal')
ouibounce(modal);
```

Comment: i have used it. it works quite well

Comment: This is specific to modals, which maybe penalized by google according to it's new Interstitial penalty as of January 10th 2017 (depends on how google is implementing it, does apply to delayed Interstitial but not necessarily exit Interstitials.)

Comment: @Goose that is only true for mobile Interstitial, which is not the case of a leave/exit intent.

Comment: Brave blocks the script

Answer (score 21):

Here's how you can do it:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', leaveFromTop);

function leaveFromTop(e){
    if( e.clientY < 0 ) // less than 60px is close enough to the top
      alert('y u leave from the top?');
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Your code actually checks for the bottom right corner..

Comment: This seems to cause issues on IE 10/11 on windows 7 as each side of the screen returns -1

Answer (score 7):

The problem I find with these techniques (like the one implemented on Ouibounce or the one proposed by Hristo Georgiev) is they also detect when the mouse enters the window if the cursor is outside the page before page load. It's not a big deal, but it might bring an unwanted behavior. An extra tweak must be done for this solution to work fine. One thing that comes to my mind right know would be to use a flag to check the mouse logic.

Comment: +1 for the tip. In my implementation I did check that.

Comment: In Hristo's answer, I didn't get the behavior you mentioned.