# How to trigger an action when we move the cursor towards the close button of a browser tab window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to **perform an action when the user is about to close the browser tab not when the user clicks the close button**. How can it be done in javascript?

Don't want to use unload or beforeunload since it is triggered when the user clicks on close button or when the user navigates to another page.

Comment: so far what you have tried

Comment: I think you need to work with native code to achieve that, different for Chrome, IE, or Firefox

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808046/how-to-detect-the-event-when-the-mouse-pointer-is-over-the-close-button-of-the-b

Comment: Only a limited set of events and actions are exposed by a browser. This I don't think that will be exposed. Check here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @Arun Kumaresh so far I have tried to get the result using pageY and clientY. But the values are not going beyond 0 so couldnt obtain the required result.

Comment: Also tried mouseleave but the action gets triggerred even when the cursor is moved away from the browser window horizontally also. Want to trigger the action only when the cursor is moved towards the top of browser window towards close button