# How to retain in same page after back button is pressed?

Tags: php

Now I want to retain in the same page when I click back button on browser. If there  is any possible please guide me.
After login if I press back button on browser the page will not go to login page it have to retain/reload into the same page.
my program in php.

Comment: It would be nice if what you're asking had some content to go along with it

Comment: In PHP means header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); check it.

Comment: check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543245/browser-back-button-handling), maybe suit your need

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Back button on the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

Comment: when i use  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); it shows The page isn't redirecting properly. how can i come over from this

Comment: Refer this link:


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926641/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-using-javascript

Comment: After successful login create a session and store status as logged in. In the login page check whether $_SESSION['status'] variable empty or not. if not empty redirect to index page. This won't make you see the login page again after login. And destroy the session in the logout

Comment: sorry Mr.sivabalan i can't understand will you please explain me briefly

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
 $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
  header("Location: ".$url);
```

Or

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```