# How to detect if the back button is pressed in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile, keypress

Please how can I detect if the back button is been pressed in a mobile phone as shown in the image below[image]

I tried using the normal way its been done on desktop like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 8){
        alert();
    }
});
```

But it's not working on mobile phones. Please anyone with a better clue?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser AND here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543245/browser-back-button-handling

Comment: @PatrickMoore He's not talking about the browser back button. He's talking about the hardware back button on android phones. Maybe you use iphone/ipad and have never seen this back button, only the home button. Android has home, back, and usually settings.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use jquery mobile.

Here is a [code sample](https://www.gajotres.net/how-to-control-back-and-forward-button-in-jquery-mobile/) (of jquery mobile)

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // do something
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Another option would be to add a 'hardwareBackPress' event listener, as demonstrated in this [react-native code sample](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler)

According to [this source](https://elementalx.org/button-mapper/android-key-codes/), to detect the 'back' key,  KEYCODE_BACK = 4 on Android.

Alternatively, you could integrate [mobile-detect.js](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/)

Hope this helps

Comment: What about vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: The code example seems not to work. - I guess you need to use `popstate` to create your own `window.history` and then the back button will react on your history and not go back to the previous website.